# Making $_GET work when there is something before it in the url address

Tags: php, html

I know the title may be confusing but essentially I'm using the $_GET method for a variable and I cannot use it if there is a #check infront of it.

For example: `http://this.org/#check?whatever=1`

So naturally if I check for the variable like this:

```
if ($_GET['whatever'] == 1) {

}
```

It won't work. So what can I add perhaps infront of the 'whatever' when I check for it to make it work? If i don't have the #check infront of the url the entire website refreshes. Any help would be appreciated, thanks for your time.

Comment: or you can just make an xmlhttprequest instead

Comment: "If i don't have the #check infront of the url the entire website refreshes." Is this the only reason you're using `#check`, or does it have another purpose?

Comment: Yes that's the only reason @Chris.

Comment: @Ghost is there really no other way I can do without xmlhttprequest?

Comment: after the hash, it doesn't get sent on the server, just make an xmlhttprequest if you don't want the whole page to reload, its just few lines

Comment: Damn, time to do some research.

Comment: @Ghost Can you specify in a little bit more detail what exactly I need to do pertaining to xmlhttprequest so I know what to research?

Comment: @JohnLeo if this url is supposed to be sent thru an anchor link, just let javascript handle the event, then under that, get the hash value, then some processing that you need, then make the request, after that, the PHP side processes the request and make the appropriate response, here's a bare simple example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27458258/onclick-javascript-on-anchor-tag-html

Comment: @Ghost If the whole page doesn't refresh though will it still update the variable?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you mean something like this. But see if this helps.

```
var url = "http://this.org/#check?whatever=1";

var splitQuestionMark = url.split('?');

var findCheck = splitQuestionMark[0].split('/');

if(findCheck[findCheck.length-1]==="#check")
{
    // use GET
}
else
{
    // don't use GET
}
```

Comment: No, I just need to know how to check for the variable if there is a #check infront of it.

Comment: I am not sure if I fully understand your question.

Comment: In the url there is a #check after the / the variable thats defined after it, in this case "Whatever" is defined to 1, but since the variable is after #check in the url, I cannot use `if ($_GET['whatever'] == 1)` to retrieve it because it will not work.

Comment: Well my answer is useless then. Sorry.

Comment: I really appreciate you trying though, happy holidays.